# SSIS truncation error

Tags: ssis, ibm-midrange, truncate, db2-400

First, I have searched and searched and searched and not found anything that helps me with this.

I have an SSIS project that will fetch a lot of data from an iSeries AS400 and it does this in two very different steps.
Step 1 works perfectly so I manage to fetch tons of info from the AS400, so the connection itself is not the issue.

Step two fails horribly with the following three error codes:

```
    [OLE DB Source [41]] Error: There was an error with OLE DB
Source.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[NAME] on OLE DB
Source.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output]. The column status returned was: "Text
was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code 
page.".

    [OLE DB Source [41]] Error: The "OLE DB Source.Outputs[OLE DB Source 
Output].Columns[NAME]" failed because truncation occurred, and the
truncation row disposition on "OLE DB Source.Outputs[OLE DB Source
Output].Columns[NAME]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error
occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

    [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
PrimeOutput method on OLE DB Source returned error code 0xC020902A.  The
component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component,
but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be
error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

I have desperately tried to find the solution to this problem and this is what I have done (which have not helped at all):

1 - Advanced Editor on SOURCE -> tab: Input and Output Properties -> OLE DB Source Output -> Output Column changed to
a) 40 (from 28) in length - no change
b) data text (from string) - complete crash
c) changed codepage from 1251 to UTF-8 - no change

2 - Fetched the information with OPENQUERY in MSSMS, it works perfectly.

3 - Screamed in frustration at the screen (didn't help).

I am at roads end. I don't know what to do anymore. Help...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find setting the Error Output for Truncation on the Source editor dialog to "Ignore Failure" gets you around the issue.

[image: Ignore Truncation "Error"]

Update - Truncation Redirect:-

Forced truncation on surname - output set to redirect 
and enabled Data Viewer on the error output

[image: DTSX wif redirect set on name]

then copied the row from the data viewer to notepad to show the error

[image: Row copied to notepad to show error]

Running the same dtsx wif truncation set to fail :-

[image: Package failure]

Comment: OMG! Thank you! It seems a bit dangerous, but it works.

Comment: It should allow you to identify if you have values incoming which exceed your defined field length(s). If you see wot I mean! As Seb said - the problem may not be in your definitions but in the data itself.....

Comment: @Mr.Glaurung...this is (probably) not a permanent answer...it should be as  Supa Stix mentions a way for you to figure out where the mismatch is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is completely maddening.

There are *two* sets of columns under OLE DB Source Output: "External Columns" and "Output Columns".

Have you tried changing the lengths of **both** columns - column "Name" under External Columns" and under "Output Columns"?

This kind of error often happens from a mismatch between the External Column definition and its corresponding Output Column.

In an OLE DB Source, External Columns are supposed to be auto-typed according to the source data types: the external provider is supposed to talk metadata to SSIS, saying "well, this column is typed String(40)", for example.  But either the provider or SSIS are often, let's say, "less than entirely competent" at getting the types and lengths right.

**UPDATE:** Have you tried checking the length of the data in the source, independently of SSIS?  Something like:

```
SELECT MAX(Len(TheReallyAnnoyingColumn)) FROM TheTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Everybody else is focused on the truncation.  I'm curious about the ***one or more characters had no match in the target code page*** part of the error message.

How is the column actually defined on the IBM i?  I'm particularly interested in the Coded Character Set Identifier (aka CCSID)

In a green screen you can use the Display File Field Description (DSPFFD) command.
[image: DSPFFD screen shot]

You could also use the iNav GUI.
[image: iNav Screenshot]

Comment: I'm not disagreeing wif you - The message is an 'or' - it is usually a truncation. This can easily be identified by changing the truncation output to redirect row and enabling  data viewer on the error output - I'll edit my answer to show wot I mean......